# recursion with no integer arguments

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am reading about recursion in algorithms in C++ by Robert Sedwick. It is mentioned as below

> In situations which involves no integer arguments at all, but rather
>   use an abstract discrete problem formulation that allows us to
>   decompose problems in to smaller ones which allows recursion.

Kindly explain what does author mean by above statement with example?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Surely that sentence is followed by an example in the actual book...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_recursion

Answer (score 1):

[QuickSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) for example - there is no integer in the problem, but an "abstract" array.

However, each recursive step divides the problem into 2 smaller sub-problems.

On the other hand, problems like recursive fibonacci - the problem is reduced to smaller problem by invoking recursively with a smaller integer.